# Performance of fopen() on win32

Tags: c, linux, winapi

I am trying to write some code that works on both Linux and Win32. The most noticeable difference I find between them (in my code) is performance of `fopen()`.  
Following code takes 5 sec on my Ubuntu and the same code takes more than 100 sec on windows XP. I would like to make a note here that ubuntu is VM while XP is on a real machine.

```
    time_t start = time(NULL);
    for(int i=0; i < 100000; ++i){
        FILE *fp = fopen("a.txt", "a");
        if (fp != NULL)
        {
            fprintf(fp, "Hello World");
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }
    time_t end = time(NULL);

    printf("\n It took %d seconds \n", end-start);
```

Clearly `fopen()` is the cause of this difference. I want to know why is it such a big difference?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Clearly fopen() is the cause of this
>   difference

No it's more likely to be filesystem flushing.
On one system when you write, or more likely call fclose(), it blocks until the bytes are physically on disk (or at least until the disk says they are) - on the other the filesystems returns straight away, even if the flies are still being written

Comment: Yup you are absolutely right. my assumption is completely wrong about fopen(). I removed fclose() just to test this and it was at par on windows.

Comment: @vrrathod: Although Martin is probably right, omitting `fclose()` still isn't a good test -- for one thing, you will exhaust the open file limit (on both OSes) and then the `if` statement won't be executed.

Comment: You could also put an fflush() before the fclose() on both of them. It's not guaranteed though - the FS can pretty much do what it wants

Comment: And the caching of files/streams is totally differen. Linux will be a lot faster if it has more RAM.
The filesystem (VAT,NTFS,EXT3,XFS,...) should be considerd too: http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/linux/pdf/Linux-FS-Performance-Comparison.pdf

Answer (score 4):

Do you use a Virus Scanner? If yes disable it first!

And some API Calls are slower on windows. E.G. your C:\ will be translated to /harddrive/something first (just an example).

Comment: This is a very valid reason, even if it may turn out not to apply in this particular case.  I saw a post recently where Windows' networking performance compared abysmally with Linux's, but the disparity disappeared when Windows Firewall was turned off.

Comment: I agree this seems plausible, possibly even likely.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot more than just the API being used here.

You are opening a file on the file system.
So the type of file system being used will affect time, as well as the hard ware speeds of the devices implementing the file system. There are just too many factors that you are not taking into account that you can accurately say X is the culprit for the slow speeds.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual C++, be aware that by default stdio now uses mutexes to enable safe multithreading.  These can be turned off with `#define _CRT_DISABLE_PERFCRIT_LOCKS`.  **[EDIT 31/12/2013]** <strike>I'm not certain, but I think Linux stdio implementations usually assume single-threaded behaviour, so don't have this locking overhead.</strike>  Linux stdio implementations likewise obey [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) and C11 standards that require safe multithreading, providing lock-free versions of functions whose names end with `_unlocked`, e.g. `fgetc_unlocked()`.

More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235505%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: And take a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eadhs8bd%28VS.80%29.aspx

Comment: Linux implementations of stdio are thread-safe as mandated by the standard. That's why there is a whole set of APIs like `fread_unlocked`.

Comment: @strcat: The only standard I could find regarding thread safety of stdio is the POSIX standard, mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3335444/47984.  Is it part of C99 or C11?  (Note that this answer was posted in 2010.)

Comment: Threading wasn't part of C until C11, so the wording wasn't added until then. Linux and other *nix operating systems implement POSIX though.

Comment: @strcat: I've made some edits.  If you have a good link for the C11 standard, please add it in -- I couldn't find anything very definitive with Google.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't relevant. This is not a normal usage scenario for I/O functions, so they don't have to be optimized for this case. Maybe windows uses an syncronous flush() while linux uses asyncronous.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Try it on a real hardware machine similar spec to the intended target
2. Use the same machine on the Windows and Linux tests - dual boot it or something.
3. Disable all third party add-ons on the windows box, especially AV software (NB: If your company IT department does not allow this, explain to them that this is a software development lab machine and need not be subject to their policy if suitably separated from the main office network)

In all likelihood they are not doing the same thing. The filesystem is probably responsible. Either the win32 box is doing a lot more flushing - possibly because it has less ram available due to other tasks - or the Linux box is running on hardware which fakes flushing and introduces another level of caching - i.e. cheats.

What level of durability do you require in your application? If the files absolutely must not disappear on power failure (e.g. mail server receiving mail) then you should fsync() them. fclose() does not guarantee to do this