# Print arguments inside thread

Tags: c, multithreading

```
void * consumer_child(void *arguments){
    Range rng = *((Range *) arguments);
    //prinnting with the range to easily identify each thread
    printf("consumer_child[%d-%d] started\n", rng.start, rng.end );

    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

When I print it, it prints memory location, not the value. I need to print the value.

In main thread start and end values are set properly. I have checked them.

in main I have set the argument as following

```
Range *rng = malloc(sizeof(*rng));
        rng->start = i * numbersPerChild;
        rng->end = (numbersPerChild * (i + 1)) -1 ;
        printf("Range for thread %d is %d to %d\n", i, rng->start, rng->end );
        printf("test print %d\n",rng->start);
pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, consumer_child, (void *)&rng );
```

Range is a struct

```
typedef struct
{
    int start;
    int end;
} Range;
```

Comment: What is Range ? how have you created your thread ?

Comment: Change `(void *)&rng` to `rng`.

Comment: @CoolGuy I have added more code please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change:

```
pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, consumer_child, (void *)&rng );
```

to:

```
pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, consumer_child, rng);
```

since `rng` is already a pointer, and you want to pass that, not its address. You don't need to cast an object pointer to `void *` in C, unless you have a variadic function that expects one and you're trying to pass it a different kind of object pointer.