# Pass argument to multiple threads

Tags: c, memory-management, pthreads

New to C, I was reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19236285/3885972) about how to properly pass an argument to a thread. What about if this argument needed to be passed to multiple threads? Where/how should I use `free()`? Say:

```
void *foo(void *i) {
    int a = *((int *) i);  
    while(1){
        printf("foo running \n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void *bar(void *i) {
    int a = *((int *) i);   
    while(1){
        printf("bar running \n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[2];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++ ) {
        int *arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));
        if ( arg == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't allocate memory for thread arg.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        *arg = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, foo, arg);
        pthread_create(&threads[1], NULL, bar, arg);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is calling `free(arg);` in `main` after spawning the threads the same thing / safe?

Comment: BTW.  Do your want the 2 `pthread_create()` calls inside the `for()` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all threads needs the exact same argument, and they are not modifying the argument, there's no need to allocate it dynamically at all, instead just declare it as a variable at function scope in the `main` function. If there's no dynamic allocation, there's no need to free it.

On the other hand if you need separate arguments in a loop like you do, you need to keep track of all arguments, for example using an array:

```
// Rest of program...

#define NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS 2

int main(void)
{
    int args[NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS];
    pthread_t threads[NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS][2];

    // Create threads
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        args[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&threads[i][0], NULL, foo, &args[i]);
        pthread_create(&threads[i][1], NULL, bar, &args[i]);
    }

    // Wait for threads to finish
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_ITERATIONS; ++i)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[i][0]);
        pthread_join(threads[i][1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program above also solves another problem you have, when you create a total of four threads but only join two.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure both threads have finished before calling `free(arg)`.

That means you can do it *after* you call `pthread_join` on both threads.

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
}
free(args);
```

Comment: I am going to accept Jaochim's answer because it also points out that in this scenario, it isn't necessary to dynamically allocate it. But +1 cause this us super useful! Thanks