# Seems like pthread_create can't get the right argument

Tags: c, multithreading

When I run the following code it seems like the printout is not right.

```
void thread_Calc(int *pos) {
  printf("recieved %d\n", *pos);
  sig = -1;

  mandel_Calc(&slices[*pos],maxIterations,&res[(*pos)*slices[*pos].imSteps*slices[*pos].reSteps]);

  counter++;
  array[counter] = *pos;
  sig = *pos;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  while (WinH % nofslices != 0) { nofslices++;}

  slice_height = WinH/nofslices;

  level = 1;

  while (1) {

    for (i=0; i<nofslices; i++){
      array[i] = -1;
    }

    y=0;
    sig = -1;
    counter = -1;
    for(i=0; i<nofslices; i++){ 
      printf("Passing %d\n", i);

      check=pthread_create(&worker[i], NULL, (void*)thread_Calc, (void*)(int *)&i);
      if (check!=0) {
        printf("Error in pthread_create\n");
        return 0;
      }

      while (sig==-1||array[counter]==-1){

      }
    }
  } 
}
```

(This is just a part of my code, so assume that every variable is right and has a value).

The result I get is something like:

```
Passing 1
Passing 2
recieved 2
recieved 2
Passing 3
Passing 4
recieved 4
recieved 4
Passing 5
Passing 6
Passing 7
Passing 8
Passing 9
```

which seems like I can't always pass the right argument in pthread_create or something.

Comment: Please post a self-contained minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 1):

@Andrew is right. You pass a pointer not a value, so as soon as you change "i" in the main thread the value is changed in the parameter received by the created thread. You need to create a copy and pass it to the thread.

See [pthread_create : passing an integer as the last argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19232957/pthread-create-passing-an-integer-as-the-last-argument)

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
   for(i=0; i<nofslices; i++){ 
      printf("Passing %d\n", i);

      check=pthread_create(&worker[i], NULL, (void*)thread_Calc, (void*)(int *)&i);
```

the value of `i` continues to change after each thread gets started.

You pass the *address* of `i`, so when it gets dereferenced in the child thread, it holds whatever value your `main` thread has put into it *at that time*.

Comment: To be honest I'm not following you completely. Do you mean that I have to pass another variable as an argument which will have the same value as `i`? Or is there another solution?

Comment: @ΥρώΚ. You need to get the *value* of `i` when you call `pthread_create()` to the child thread.  By passing the *address* of `i` and then dereferencing it in the child thread, you're getting whatever value `i` has in the main thread when it's dereferenced. The quick, dirty hack is to pass the *value* of `i` as the "pointer": `pthread_create( ... ( void * ) i ):`.  Note the *lack* of the address-of `&`.  Then in the child thread: `void *thread_Calc( void *arg ) { int i = ( int ) arg; ...}`  Technically undefined behavior, but it does what's needed quickly - and most importantly, clearly.

Comment: Ooh, I see! I'll try that

Comment: @ΥρώΚ. Remember - that method is a hack.  It works on most platforms, but a proper way is linked in Vicente Sirvent's answer.  I just think the hack communicates the intent better - it's more clear, with less code (and it fits in a comment...)

Comment: That hack works only when void* is the same size as int. If you go to a 64 bits architecture I think that should not even compile...

Comment: @VicenteSirvent Oh, it's definitely playing with fire.  But it's usually safe for small non-negative `int` values, such as those seen in a `for`-loop used to start threads as you're not likely going to create 2 billion+ (assuming 32-bit `int`).  With an explicit cast, it should compile on just about any platform - it does on Linux with GCC (ask me how I know...) - and although I've never run into one, I can easily imagine a platform where it would fail at run-time.

Comment: Anyway, both of you guys really helped me! Thank you very much for your interest.