# Threads not running at same time

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I made a concurrency class to test out threads. since I wanted to find out the best way to run threads at the same time.

I am surprised by my results:

```
test
test
Othertest
test
Othertest
test
test
test
```

The results I expected were for the threads to come back randomly yet they seem to come back consistently in the same order! Does anyone know why? Does this mean that they are not running concurrently? How might I go about getting them to run at the same time?

Here is my code:

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        new Thread(new ThreadTest().test()).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadTest().test()).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadTest().otherTest()).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadTest().test()).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadTest().otherTest()).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadTest().test()).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadTest().test()).start();
        new Thread(new ThreadTest().test()).start();
    }

    public  Runnable test() throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
        System.out.println("test");
        return null;
    }

    public  Runnable otherTest() throws InterruptedException{
        Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
        System.out.println("Othertest");
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: They aren't actually running anything in the Thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have better luck with this:

```
public class ThreadTest {
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
{
    new Thread(test).start();
    new Thread(test).start();
    new Thread(otherTest).start();
    new Thread(test).start();
    new Thread(otherTest).start();
    new Thread(test).start();
    new Thread(test).start();
    new Thread(test).start();
}

public static Runnable test = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run()  {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("test");
    }
};

public static Runnable otherTest = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Othertest");
    }
};
```

}

The idea is to pass an instance of `Runnable` as an argument to the `Thread` constructor. You are not really doing that, because `test()` and `otherTest()` are both returning `null`. The above code shows one way of running the threads in the way that I'm guessing you want. Other approaches are certainly possible.

Comment: `Runnable`s are not allowed to throw `InterruptedException`. You actually have to catch those exceptions and interrupt the current thread when that happens.

Comment: thanks I was just going to comment on that so i edited his comment

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young - Oops. You're right about that. I see that kevinn205 went ahead and corrected it.

Comment: This example Would not be thread safe either I presume unless I threw a synchonized or went back to initialing a new threadtest as well correct?

Comment: @kevinn205 - As long as you have multiple threads calling `System.out.println` without synchronization, there's the possibility of garbled output. (Although you can usually get away with it. See, e.g., [this discussion thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459657/synchronization-and-system-out-println).) Creating instances of `ThreadTest` won't help with that; you need synchronization. I don't know what you mean by "unless I threw a synchronized".

Comment: public static setItem(String item){String bob= item; system.out.println(item)} new thread.setItem(); new thread.setItem(); couldnt this code give the wrong value for bob because of the other thread?

Comment: @kevinn205 - That code is not legal Java, so it's hard to know what you're intending. If `bob` is a local variable (as it appears to be), then there's a separate `bob` for each thread and the threads won't interfere with one another.

Answer (score 2):

The `Thread` constructor accepts a `Runnable` on which the `Thread` will eventually execute the `run()` method. Right now you aren't returning a `Runnable` object. you are returning `null`. So the execution you do in your `test()` and `otherTest()` methods is executed synchronously.

All your execution happens in one thread. This

```
new Thread(new ThreadTest().test()).start();
```

executes `test()`, sleeps for a second, prints `"test"` and returns `null`. The `start()` call doesn't do anything because the `Runnable` is `null`. This continues for each other call you do.

You need to put everything in your `test()` and `otherTest()` methods inside a `Runnable#run()` method. For example

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
         Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
         System.out.println("test");
    }
}).start();
```

Consider the source code of the `run()` method of `Thread` class, which is executed when `start()` is called

```
@Override
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

Where `target` is the `Runnable` reference you pass in the constructor. Obviously, if it is `null`, it won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you, that definitely gives a good explanation of that was happening

Answer (score 1):

Your `Thread` implementation is *WRONG*.

You should either implement `Runnable` and implement `run()` method or
you should extend `Thread` class and override `run()` method.

What is happening is that your `test()` method or `otherTest()` is being called just as any method calls. And since you don't have any `run()` method your `Thread.start()` wont simply run anything.

Try changing your method like below.

```
public Runnable test() {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
                System.out.println("test");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}


public Runnable otherTest() {
    System.out.println("Othertest");
    return new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random() * 1000));
                    System.out.println("Othertest");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mean "new Thread(new ThreadTest().test()).start();"? how should it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your `test` and `otherTest` methods as `Runnable` implementations. Like so:

```
private static class Test implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}

private static class OtherTest implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Othertest");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    new Thread(new OtherTest()).start();
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    new Thread(new OtherTest()).start();
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
    new Thread(new Test()).start();
}
```

You could, of course, try to reduce the duplication a little:

```
private enum Runnables implements Runnable {
    TEST {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!sleep()) return;
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    },
    OTHER_TEST {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!sleep()) return;
            System.out.println("Othertest");
        }
    };

    static boolean sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep((long) (Math.random()*1000));
            return true;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return false;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Thread(Runnables.TEST).start();
    new Thread(Runnables.TEST).start();
    new Thread(Runnables.OTHER_TEST).start();
    new Thread(Runnables.TEST).start();
    new Thread(Runnables.OTHER_TEST).start();
    new Thread(Runnables.TEST).start();
    new Thread(Runnables.TEST).start();
    new Thread(Runnables.TEST).start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, Interesting it appears that you can wrap several runnables into a runnables enum and since you call them using implements it makes then a runnable when you access them using Runnables.test