# Make Clojure's println "thread-safe" in the same way as in Java

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure

While playing around with concurrent calls to `println` in Clojure I found that its behaviour is different from Java's `System.out.println`.

What in Java I would write

```java
class Pcalls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable[] fns = new Runnable[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            fns[i] = new Runnable() {
                @Override public void run() {
                    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                        System.out.println("Hello iteration " + i);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        for (Runnable fn : fns) new Thread(fn).start();
    }
}
```

I paraphrased in Clojure as:

```clj
(doall (apply pcalls
              (repeat 3 #(dotimes [i 5] (println "Hello iteration" (inc i))))))
```

Unfortunately, in the Clojure version the output lines often appear interleaved:

```
Hello iterationHello iteration  1
Hello iteration Hello iteration 2
Hello iteration 3
1
Hello iteration 4
1
Hello iteration Hello iteration5
 Hello iteration 2
Hello iteration 23

Hello iteration Hello iteration 4
3Hello iteration 
5
Hello iteration 4
Hello iteration 5
(nil nil nil)
```

In Java this [never happens](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9459657), every message is printed on its own line.

Can you explain how and why Clojure's `println` differs from Java's, and how to arrive at a similar kind of "thread-safe" behaviour with `println` in Clojure?

Comment: http://yellerapp.com/posts/2014-12-11-14-race-condition-in-clojure-println.html is another option -- it concatenates everything to a single string and prints in one go. So there's no interleaving of output. Essentially just `(defn safe-println [& more] (.write *out* (str (clojure.string/join " " more) "\n")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, `println` sends output to the writer that is the currently-bound value for `*out*`. There are a couple of reasons that calls to this are not atomic:

1. The `println` function is multiple arity. If handed multiple objects, it makes multiple writes to `*out*`.
2. Calls to `println` are delegated to an internal multimethod called `print-method` (which can be extended to add print support for custom types). The `print-method` implementation for non-string objects, especially collection types, can make multiple writes to `*out*`. This is in contrast to Java's `println` which will call `.toString` on the object and make a single write.

If you want atomic println's, you'll probably have to explicitly synchronize your calls, e.g.:

```
(let [lock (Object.)]
  (defn sync-println [& args]
    (locking lock (apply println args))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the *how*! But now that I know about `locking` I prefer @noisesmith's solution that locks on `*out*`. Or do you have a specific reason for using the lock object?

Comment: In general I prefer for my code not to lock on objects that it doesn't own. You never know what else might be locking on `*out*`, or why. Chances are it's OK, but it only takes one misbehaved writer to hog the lock and screw things up for everybody.

Comment: This explains why it is so, but not why it was made so? It could have been that println delegates a str-method and performs concatenation after going through all arguments and performs a single write to the *out* stream for example.

Comment: I think in this case it makes more sense to lock on `*out*`, because the goal is to synchronize writes to *out*, so if something else you don't know about has a hold on *out*, you probably want to respect that as well and wait before writing to it.

Answer (score 6):

A convention in clojure is to lock `*out*`, which refers to the location printed to.

```
user> (doall (apply pcalls
            (repeat 3 #(dotimes [i 5]
                             (locking *out*
                               (println "Hello iteration" (inc i)))))))
Hello iteration 1
Hello iteration 1
Hello iteration 2
Hello iteration 3
Hello iteration 4
Hello iteration 5
Hello iteration 1
Hello iteration 2
Hello iteration 3
Hello iteration 4
Hello iteration 5
Hello iteration 2
Hello iteration 3
Hello iteration 4
Hello iteration 5
(nil nil nil)
```

Answer (score 4):

New in Clojure 1.10, one can also make use of `tap>` to synchronize println, as such:

```
(add-tap println)
(tap> [1 2 3 4])
;> [1 2 3 4]
```

Now you can send to `tap>` to print in the order tap receives in a thread safe manner:

```
(doall (apply pcalls
              (repeat 3 #(dotimes [i 5] (tap> (str "Hello iteration" " " (inc i)))))))
Hello iteration 1
Hello iteration 1
Hello iteration 2
Hello iteration 3
Hello iteration 4
Hello iteration 5
Hello iteration 1
Hello iteration 2
Hello iteration 3
Hello iteration 4
Hello iteration 5
Hello iteration 2
Hello iteration 3
Hello iteration 4
Hello iteration 5
(nil nil nil)
```

Just note that `tap>` is arity-1, so you can't pass it more than one thing, which means in this case you have to use `str` first to concatenate what you want printed.

```
With `tap>`, you can also have it do synchronized pretty printing:

(add-tap (bound-fn* clojure.pprint/pprint))
(tap> {:a 100 :b 200 :c 300 :d 200 :f 400 :g 400000000 :h 3992 :l {:k 10203 :f 39945 :o 29394}})

{:a 100,
 :b 200,
 :c 300,
 :d 200,
 :f 400,
 :g 400000000,
 :h 3992,
 :l {:k 10203, :f 39945, :o 29394}}
```

Under the hood, `tap>` uses a `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue` to synchronize the calls to it.

Also note that `tap>` is asynchronous. So while things are being printed, it won't block. That means that if you quit the app before it is done printing, it won't finish:

```
(doall (apply pcalls
              (repeat 3 #(dotimes [i 5] (tap> (str "Hello iteration" " " (inc i)))))))
(System/exit 0)

"Hello iteration 1"
"Hello iteration 2"
"Hello iteration 3"
"Hello iteration 4"
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, an alternative to using Clojure's `locking` is to rely on the synchronisation of `System.out` (to which `*out*` is bound by default) provided by the Java host.

```
(doall (apply pcalls
              (repeat 3 #(dotimes [i 5]
                           (.println *out* (str "Hello iteration " (inc i)))))))
```

```
(defn out-println [& args]
  (.println *out* (apply str (interpose \space args))))
```

But note that the answers to [Synchronization and System.out.println](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9459657) suggest that technically the Java API does not guarantee synchronisation for `System.out.println`. And of course `*out*` can be rebound in Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this problem with core.async:

```
(def print-chan (chan 10))

(defn aprintln [& message]
  (>!! print-chan message))

(defn start-printer! [] (thread (while true
                                  (apply println (<!! print-chan)))))

(defn do-a-thing [] (aprintln "Doing a thing"))

(defn do-another-thing [] (aprintln "Doing another thing"))

(defn -main []
  (start-printer!)
  (future (do-a-thing))
  (do-another-thing))
```

This will ensure that your outputs don't interleave, no matter how many threads call `aprintln` at once.