# printf in sub-thread outputs nothing

Tags: clojure

*clojure 1.10.1*

*println* at least outputs in a sub-thread but *printf* doesn't at all.

```
(.start (Thread. #(println "Hi !"))) ; => Hi

(.start (Thread. #(printf "%s\n" "Hi")))
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662301/make-clojures-println-thread-safe-in-the-same-way-as-in-java) seemingly dealt with *println* synchronization. Any advice on *printf*?

**@EDIT**

Above, both *println* and *printf* output on the [clj](https://clojure.org/guides/deps_and_cli) REPL. *println* outputs but *printf* doesn't as standalone program.

Comment: CNR -- works just fine when I run it.

Comment: What's the context? Is stdout pointing to a TTY or to a non-TTY device? (That modifies the default buffering behavior).

Comment: It's [tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) if no mistaken.

Comment: Then, once again, I simply can't reproduce this. Doesn't happen in the ideone sandbox either; see https://ideone.com/PkEVsh

Comment: I saw you called *Thread/sleep* afterwords, then *printf* outputs.

Comment: If I didn't call `Thread/sleep`, the child thread could be killed because the whole program exited before it finished starting up and was able to execute any code. (Or at least, I'd need to worry about whether the child thread was marked as a "daemon thread" to prevent that). It's nothing specific to `printf` or `println`. That's not a problem at a REPL, because the REPL won't automatically exit unless its stdin is closed.

Comment: By default Java starts a [non-daemon](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/Ti0-mpNnVxk) child thread, the parent need wait till the child completes.

Comment: ...anyhow, what does that have to do with this question, and my observation above that it isn't reproducible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212632/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-sof).

Answer (score 0):

For the standalone program, `println` prints to the standard output, which is a PrintWriter that flushes an internal buffer after printing. From the [JavaDoc for PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html):

> [...] Optionally, a PrintStream can be created so as to flush automatically; this means that the flush method is automatically invoked after a byte array is written, one of the println methods is invoked, or a newline character or byte ('\n') is written.

`printf` does not do the flushing, so (unless it's done by the REPL) there's no forcing function for it to be printed before the program ends. If you want to flush it manually, you can always do `(.flush System/out)` or `(println)` yourself.

**Edit**: you can see it in the sources of the JDK: [println()](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/cf44386c8fe3/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l771) calls a private method called [newLine()](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/cf44386c8fe3/src/share/classes/java/io/PrintStream.java#l507) that does the flushing:

```java
// ... snip
            synchronized (this) {
                ensureOpen();
                textOut.newLine();
                textOut.flushBuffer();
                charOut.flushBuffer();
                if (autoFlush)
                    out.flush();
```

Comment: The test appended *\n* to *printf*. Using *(.printf (System/out) ...)* also printed out.