# java statement execution in threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

If thread is executing following statement (suppose value of x is 1) and sleeps at point 'Here' and some other thread changes value of x.(suppose to 10) what will be the output?

```
System.out.println(/Here/++x);
```

Comment: You may want to look at answers for [Synchronization and System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459657/synchronization-and-system-out-println) post.

Comment: This depends on the declaration and actual reference of x in the context of every thread

Answer (score 0):

If the thread running the `System.out` stops before it does any processing on the `++x` and then the value of `x` is changed on another thread to `10`, the printed statement will be whatever `Here` evaluates to, followed by `11`.

Answer (score 0):

Which ever one comes first. But you should know that there is no way it could change if the command is being executed. Even if the system is multi-core it will first finish the command and then jump on to the next. Except if it calls a big function, which is a different topic.

Comment: What is your definition of "*big function*"?