# What is the difference between using synchronized println and just println in Groovy for a threaded script?

Tags: java, multithreading, groovy

What is the difference between using synchronized println and just println in Groovy for a threaded script?

```
synchronized out(message) {
println(message)
}

def thread1 = Thread.start {
out "TEST"
}
def thread2 = Thread.start {
out "TEST"
}
def thread3 = Thread.start {
out "TEST"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, until you call single println command. One println is internally synchronized. But if your out contains multiple print statements, there may be such situation, illistrated below

```
out(int threadId){ 
   println("line 1 T$threadId")
   println("line 2 T$threadId")
}

Execution may flow like
//output by 2 threads
line 1 T1 // thread 1 entered out
// thread 1 was interrupted
// thread 2 entered out
line 1 T2
line 2 T2 //end of thread 2 out
// Thread 1 resumed
line 2 T1
```

As we see, output is messed. synchronized fixes that problem

See also SO answer about println inner synchronisation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459886/1601606

Comment: I doubt `println` is atomic. `+=` isn't atomic. Did you mean `synchronized`?

Comment: @tim Yes, I meant atomic, as monolite construction, that will be executed as one. Thanks for comment! I know about 'atomic' term, but little confused with it usage here. I corrected the answer.