# Understanding method synchronization in Java

Tags: java, outputstream

I know thread synchronization. But in this code from the book Java Network Programming by Merlin Hughes, it is written that the `println` method synchronizes on `System.out`. I don’t understand how a method could be synchronized on `System.out`.

Second question I wanna ask: Is the `println` function an overridden method or is it just a user defined method in this code?

```
import java.io.*;

public class SimpleOut  {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            println (args[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void println(String msg) throws IOException {
        synchronized (System.out) {
            for (int i=0 ; i<msg.length(); i++) {
                System.out.write(msg.charAt (i) & 0xff);
            }
            System.out.write('\n');
        }
        System.out.flush();
    }

}
```

Comment: You can synchronize on any object via a reference - why would you expect `System.out` to be different? And the `println` method in your code can't be overriding anything - it's static...

Comment: is system.out an object ,if yes? whos object is it? and when was it created? 
the reason i asked println to an overridden method is that println is a predefined function ,please explain

Comment: refer what is system.out http://javapapers.com/core-java/system-out-println/

Comment: Synchronizing on a globally available reference, which can be reassigned (using `System.setOut()`) doesn't look like a very good idea to me. The method should use its own private, final lock.

Comment: @JunaidShirwani: Well `out` is a class field in the `System` class. You'd be synchronizing on the object that the value of the field refers to...

Answer (score 1):

You can synchronize over any Object/Instance. `out` is an class variable declared in the class `java.lang.System`.

```
public final static PrintStream out
```

Answer (score 0):

Synchronization is mechanism that you do it on specified 'resource' ~ reference. System.out is also that resource. There is also link to post about that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459886/1370062)

This is also very good blog to understand some harder things in java I am reading it when I have time there is lot of useful stuff. [Java revisited](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html)