# Is System.out.println thread-safe by default?

Tags: multithreading, java

`System.out` returns the "standard" output stream - a `PrintStream`. The *javadoc* of `PrintStream` tells me nothing about thread safety but looking at the source of the *OpenJDK* and the *OracleJDK* tells me that `println` is synchronized.

```
/**
 * Prints a String and then terminate the line.  This method behaves as
 * though it invokes <code>{@link #print(String)}</code> and then
 * <code>{@link #println()}</code>.
 *
 * @param x  The <code>String</code> to be printed.
 */
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

That fits pretty well to my experiences: Calling `System.out.println()` never created 'mixed' output when calling from different threads.

So my question(s):

1. Can I rely on this behavior (using different *JVMs*)?
2. Is there some documentation that I missed which describes this behavior?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459657/synchronization-and-system-out-println

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the documentation of `PrintStream`, its superclass `FilterStream`, and *its* superclass `OutputStream` all fail to say anything about thread safety or synchronization, in theory you cannot rely on it, it's not part of the contract.

I think it would be *surprising* if someone produced a `PrintStream` class that didn't do what Oracle's does in this regard, but I've been surprised before.

Comment: This! Unless it's clearly documented, it's open to interpretation.

Comment: Having a `PrintStream` that isn’t thread safe would be more than just surprising, it would also create an unsolvable problem. To make it thread safe, you had to guard *every* access to it, but unfortunately, `System.out` is a globally visible resource and a lot of code accessing it is outside your control. We’re not only talking about 3rd party libraries but also logging code inside the JRE itself.

Comment: @Holger: You're assuming `System.out` is supposed to and/or claims to serialize output from multiple threads. I'm not aware of that claim being made anywhere. If a logging library is relying on output through `System.out` across multiple threads not being intermixed, well, they're relying on something they shouldn't be relying on. (Perhaps they *ought* to be able to rely on it, but the guarantee isn't there.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I’m not assuming that `System.out` is thread safe, I’m saying that if it isn’t, it is *impossible* to make it thread safe, as every attempt to do so implies relying on a particular behavior of *every* other code that accesses `System.out`, including the already existing log handler, provided by the JRE, that prints to the console. This handler *might* serialize logging, but as long as you don’t know, how it’s done, you can’t ensure compatibility with it. Recall, thread safety requires synchronizing on the *same* object or acquiring the *same* lock in *all* cases.

Comment: @Holger: *"I’m not assuming that System.out is thread safe, I’m saying that if it isn’t, it is impossible to make it thread safe..."* Absolutely. I understood that. I misunderstood the rest of your comment, I think. :-) I read it with an implied "...therefore you can assume it is synchronized." which absolutely is not present in your text. Sorry about that.