# System.out.println() doesn't work as i want in the for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, println

Firstly, I'm sorry for my bad english. I wrote my problem in the forums that speak my language. But I did not get an answer. I hope you can help me.

When I write the for loop, the `System.out.println()` or `JTextArea.setText()` command starts to work when the loop is over. Part of my  codes:

```
for(int pixelCount = 0;pixelCount<pixelLength;pixelCount++){

  System.out.println("Progress..:"+pixelCount+"/"+pixelLength);



  int x = pixelCount%Image.getWidth();
  int y = pixelCount/Image.getWidth();
  if(isChange==1){
    if(new Color(Image.getRGB(x, y)).getRed()%2==0){
        Image.setRGB(x, y,new Color(new Color(Image.getRGB(x, y)).getRed()+1,
                                    new Color(Image.getRGB(x, y)).getGreen(),
                                    new Color(Image.getRGB(x, y)).getBlue(),
                                    new Color(Image.getRGB(x, y)).getAlpha()).getRGB());}
}
```

The loop is sometimes very long. So I print it on the screen to see the progress of the loop. The loop starts when I press the button. But when I press the button, the System.out.println() command looks afterwards.

EDIT: How should I write the progress in the loop?

EDIT: I solved the problem, friends. The System.out.println () command works fine. There is a replace command before the for loop starts. The program spends time there before the for loop starts. Thanks everyone who took the time and helped me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronization and System.out.println](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459657/synchronization-and-system-out-println)

Comment: @Guy there is no synchronization or multithreaded but  in the OP's code so your duplicate is not relevant here

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt there are probably more accurate duplicates, but the idea is that `System.out.println` is not synchronized, that's why the output appears only after the loop is over.

Comment: @Guy There is no threading involved. The fact that System.out.println is not synchronized has absolutely zero to do with the OP's problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either call `System.out.flush()` after you print, or use `System.err.println`.

`System.out` is a buffered stream that prints when the buffer is full, when you flush it, or st other times that your system finds useful. `System.err` is unbuffered and is also the preferred stream for debug and diagnostic information, such as progress information.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried both. But It's still not working. 
Only the System.err.println () command was red.

Answer (score 2):

Using of System.our.flush() was already mentionned by Erwin Bolwidt. The way output works strongly depends on type of OS (and terminal) you use. For example for *nix systems you could consider some kind of library similar to Curses (it is originally a C library, but I'm sure there are some Java implementations).