# Spring Scheduling in Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializer, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.

Technologies used:

Spring Boot 2.0.0.M6 , Java 8, maven.

I've created this class

```
com.iberia.task.scheduled

    public class IberiaAssetHandlerJob {


        private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

        @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * ?")
        public void reportCurrentTime() {

            System.out.println("The time is now {}" + dateFormat.format(new Date()));

        }
    }
```

expecting to see the message every minute

and my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class IberiaWebUtilsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(IberiaWebUtilsApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

but I don't see any message in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@Scheduled` annotation only works for Spring managed beans. You didn't put a `@Component` annotation on top of `IberiaAssetHandlerJob`, nor did you manually create a bean (using the `@Bean` annotation).

---

Also, be aware that `PrintStream` (the underlying class used by `System.out`) [isn't necessarily thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9459886), so if you have other threads writing to `System.out` as well, then you may get strange results, that's why it's recommended to use a logging framework (like [lzagkaretos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8098978/lzagkaretos) mentioned in his answer). This also allows you to use placeholders like `{}` as well, for example:

```
logger.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```

Make sure to use multiple arguments rather than concatenating everything to a single string in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `System.out.println(...)` with a Logger in order to see the message and declare class as Spring managed bean as [g00glen00b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915448/g00glen00b) states in his answer.

```
private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(IberiaAssetHandlerJob.class);

log.info("The time is now {}" + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
```