# Method synchronization working differently with different object initializations

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

As per my code, I have three classes:

Display:

```
class Display
{
    synchronized public void wish(String name)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            System.out.print("Good Morning: ");
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
            }
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

MyThread:

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    String name;
    Display d;


    MyThread(Display d, String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.d = d;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        d.wish(name); 
    }
}
```

Demo:

```
class SynchronizedDemo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Display d = new Display();
        MyThread mt1 = new MyThread(d, "foo");
        MyThread mt2 = new MyThread(d, "bar");

        mt1.start();
        mt2.start();
    }
}
```

It's working fine when I run the Demo class and I get the following output:

```
Good Morning: bar
Good Morning: bar
Good Morning: bar
Good Morning: foo
Good Morning: foo
Good Morning: foo

Output completed (6 sec consumed) - Normal Termination
```

Here I totally understand the fact that sleep() method will not release the object lock so once a thread gets into the wish() method, it finishes its work, then only another thread may get the chance.

But if I change my MyThread class as follows:

```
class MyThread extends Thread
{
    String name;
    Display d;


    MyThread(Display d, String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.d = d;
    }

    Display d1 = new Display();

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        d1.wish(name); 
    }
}
```

Now, the only change is that I am using Display class object that I have initialized inside MyThread class. But the out was totally unexpected to me:

```
Good Morning: Good Morning: foo
Good Morning: bar
Good Morning: bar
Good Morning: foo
Good Morning: bar
foo

Output completed (3 sec consumed) - Normal Termination
```

Here it can clearly be understood with the output that as soon as one thread goes on sleep, other is getting the chance to execute wish().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Synchronization and System.out.println](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459657/synchronization-and-system-out-println)

Comment: Synchronization happens on the instance. When you synchronize a (non-static) method, it's equivalent to wrapping the body in `synchronized (this) {}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second example, `d1` is a member of the `MyThread` class that's initialized inline (which is just syntactic sugar over initializing it in the constructor). Each instance of `MyThread` has its own `Display` instance, and thus the synchronization is pointless - those are two different objects, synchronizing on two different monitors.