# While loop blocking other threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am waiting for a boolean to change with the while loop, but the while loop never ends? I'm probably somehow stupid about this

Code that does work. but the while loop never ends and my code when the boolean has changed doesn't get executed:

```java
while(!myCoolBoolean);
//my code when the boolean has changed to true
```

It's a bit weird, because it works when I do:

```java
while(!myCoolBoolean) {
    System.out.print();
}
//my code again
```

Any help?
EDIT: The while loop is actually in a thread, and myCoolBoolean is being changed in an another thread

Comment: Where does the `myCoolBoolean` supposedly change? Please [edit] your question and add a [mcve], because what you've posted now **should** never end...

Comment: You are blocking the entire process with your while loop. `System.out.print();` gives the processor some time to execute other threads (that will then apparently update the variable).

Comment: also related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459657/is-multi-thread-output-from-system-out-println-interleaved - it shows that while this is not guaranteed, implementations of `System.out.print` are usually synchronized internally. It *can*  therefore cause changes from other threads to  become visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare:

`volatile boolean myCoolBoolean;`

Comment: Thank you, never knew what "volatile" is.

Comment: It basically ensures that thread which runs your `while` loop does not have stale value of the `myCoolBoolean` variable

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are trying to wait for the value of `myCoolBoolean` to be changed from another thread. If it's your code that's updating `myCoolBoolean`, you should use `wait()` and `notify()` instead.

1. Initialize an object somewhere so that both threads can access it.

   ```
   public Object myCoolObject = new Object();
   ```
2. Instead of your while loop, write

   ```
   synchronized(myCoolObject) {
       myCoolObject.wait();
   }
   ```
3. In the place where you would have updated `myCoolBoolean`, do

   ```
   synchronized(myCoolObject) {
       myCoolObject.notify();
   }
   ```

`wait();` will pause the first thread until the second thread calls `notify();`.

If you cannot change the code that updates `myCoolBoolean`, you can change your loop to

```
while (!myCoolBoolean) {
    wait(1);
}
```

This way your code will pause one millisecond per iteration to give the other thread time to update the flag. Without the `wait(1);` it will use up all your processing time just executing the loop.