# What are the main differences between fwrite and write?

Tags: c++, c

I'm currently writing a callback function in `C`:

```
static size_t writedata(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream){

        size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE)*stream);
        return written;
}
```

This function is going to be used in another function, which does a `HTTP` request, retrieves the request, and writes it to the local machine. That `writedata` function will be used for the later part. The whole operation has to be `multithreaded`, so I was in doubt between `write` and `fwrite`. Could someone help me outlining the differences between `write()` and `fwrite()` in `C`, so I could choose which one best fits into my problem?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`fwrite` writes to a `FILE*`, i.e. a (potentially) buffered `stdio` stream. It's specified by the ISO C standard. Additionally, on POSIX systems, [`fwrite` is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/468105/166749) to a certain degree.

`write` is a lower-level API based on file descriptors, described in the POSIX standard. It doesn't know about buffering. If you want to use it on a `FILE*`, then fetch its file descriptor with `fileno`, but be sure to manually lock and flush the stream before attempting a `write`.

Use `fwrite` unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: One thing to note, though, is that you *probably* shouldn't access a FILE* structure (which includes, but is not limited to, calling fread/fwrite) from multiple threads, whereas it's generally safer to do so with low-level file descriptors... but still not a good idea without some synchronization :)

Comment: @fred-foo I am curious what is going to happen if I call write() multiple times with 1 thread without locking nor flushing.  Given fwrite() is thread safe while write() not, I would imagine that write() will be faster than fwrite() when writing to a ramdrive.  Tho, my test indicates otherwise -- about 20x slower.  Any idea?

Comment: `write` actually is thread safe.  The difference in performance is probably from the buffering: `fwrite` will make fewer calls to `write` and thus reduce system call overhead.  Note that many implementations will optimize out the locking of `fwrite` in a program that only has one thread.

Comment: A drawback of `fwrite()` as per ISO C is that there is no way to get the reason a write fails, e.g. a good `errno`-based error message such as `no space left on device` or `broken pipe` or similar.

Answer (score 8):

One very noticeable difference is write is atomic and fwrite isn't.

https://yarchive.net/comp/linux/wakekill.html

Using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  if (fork() == 0) {
    FILE* h = fopen("file.txt", "a");
    char* line =
        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      if (write(fileno(h), line, strlen(line)) != strlen(line)) {
        perror("Could not append line to file");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    if (fclose(h) != 0) {
      perror("Could not close file");
      exit(1);
    }
  } else {
    FILE* h = fopen("file.txt", "a");
    char* line =
        "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      if (write(fileno(h), line, strlen(line)) != strlen(line)) {
        perror("Could not append line to file");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    if (fclose(h) != 0) {
      perror("Could not close file");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You will get output like this, no interleaving lines:

```
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Using:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  if (fork() == 0) {
    FILE* h = fopen("file.txt", "a");
    char* line =
        "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      if (fwrite(line, 1, strlen(line), h) != strlen(line)) {
        perror("Could not append line to file");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    if (fclose(h) != 0) {
      perror("Could not close file");
      exit(1);
    }
  } else {
    FILE* h = fopen("file.txt", "a");
    char* line =
        "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      if (fwrite(line, 1, strlen(line), h) != strlen(line)) {
        perror("Could not append line to file");
        exit(1);
      }
    }
    if (fclose(h) != 0) {
      perror("Could not close file");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You will get output like this, interleaving lines:

```
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: `write()` is not guaranteed to be atomic, that's implementation-defined. Write may give the given buffer in one go to the underlying OS system call, but what happens after that is up to the OS. For example, if the `write()` is large enough, you may still observe interleaved output in files written to disk, or output written to a terminal.

Comment: If the implementation is Linux or Unix it is, without speaking for every operating system in the world.

Comment: On Unix (and Linux) it is only true for `O_APPEND` writes to regular files, and it is not true when writing to pipes, which have less guarantees, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942915/understanding-concurrent-file-writes-from-multiple-processes/12943431#12943431) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35260110/263061) (answers of the same question). So it is a property of the location that's being written to, not `write()` by itself. Also, `write()` can return a short write; in your example it's handled as an error, but generally needs "retrying the rest".

Answer (score 0):

The `write` function is a call that your program makes to the operating system and therefore it is slower than `fwrite`. It also lacks of **buffering** which makes it even **slower** because as the philosophy of buffering suggests: "It is faster to handle many portions of small files rather than a big one." It is also important that `write` is not part of the c standard, so you probably won't find it non-POSIX systems and (rarely) the apropriate use will differ. You should also known that fwrite and fread are some times implemented using `write` and `read` (a simple implementation can be found in the chapter about Unix of K&R).

Another noteable thing is that `read` and `write` use  [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor), but fread and fwrite use the  **FILE pointers** which are actually pointers which contain file descriptors and other info about the file opened.

Comment: Lacking buffering doesn't make it slower exactly - if you're writing fixed size memory chunks (or managing your own buffering already) for eg, buffering may give unnecessary overhead. It's better to say, using `fwrite` is preferable if you would benefit from buffered writing.