# Atomic writes to a file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm reading about [`pipe(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)s in Linux and came across the following thing:

> POSIX.1  says  that  `write(2)`s  of less than `PIPE_BUF` bytes must be
>   atomic: the output data is written to the pipe as a contiguous
>   sequence.  Writes of more than `PIPE_BUF` bytes may be nonatomic: the
>   kernel may interleave the data with data written by other processes. 
>   POSIX.1 requires `PIPE_BUF` to be at least 512 bytes.  (On Linux,
>   `PIPE_BUF` is  4096  bytes.)

This is not quite clear. Does POSIX require that all writes less then `PIPE_BUF` are atomic? Or this is true to pipes created with `pipe(int[2], int)` only?

Comment: What other syscall creates a pipe? (edit: `mkfifo()`, I guess...)

Comment: @Shawn `pipe2(int[], int)`?

Comment: @Shawn `open` if you give it a named pipe, but OP is asking about writes in general.

Comment: @SomeName `pipe` only takes an `int[2]`. There is no second argument. `pipe2` is Linux only (not part of POSIX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted behavior is pipe specific (but applies to all pipes, no matter how they were created (e.g. by `pipe`, `mkfifo`+`open`, etc)).

From the [POSIX description of `write`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html):

> Write requests to a pipe or FIFO shall be handled in the same way as a regular file with the following exceptions:
>
> - [...]
> - Write requests of {PIPE_BUF} bytes or less shall not be interleaved with data from other processes doing writes on the same pipe. Writes of greater than {PIPE_BUF} bytes may have data interleaved, on arbitrary boundaries, with writes by other processes, whether or not the O_NONBLOCK flag of the file status flags is set.

Comment: Interesting. So we don't have any atomicity guarantees when it comes to `write`ing to regular files? Even if we are considering `etx4` file-system specific writes?

Comment: > _by `pipe`, `mkfifo` / `open`, etc_ So `open`ing a regular file also creates a pipe?

Comment: @SomeName POSIX makes no guarantees about other writes; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943431/1848654. No, opening a regular file does not create a pipe, but `mkfifo` does not create a regular file.