# Joining results from ThreadPoolExecutor as available

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, python-multithreading

I'm using ThreadPoolExecutor to run several simultaneous queries of an API simultaneously. I'd like to return the results as they become available and perform some action on them. I found [this post](https://fed_reactions_df%20=%20pd.DataFrame()%20for%20future%20in%20concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_lst):%20%20%20result_df%20=%20format_columns_in(future.result())%20%20%20result_df.to_csv(%27fed-reactions.csv%27,%20mode=%27a%27,%20index=True,%20header=True)) which details the various methods for handling returned results from ThreadPoolExecutor quite helpful. However, it seems like my code is still waiting for all of the API queries to finish before it performs the subsequent actions I'm requesting on the returns from the API. While my code works, I feel like I'm missing something. Is this the best way, or even the correct way to structure this?

Here is an example of my code:

```
futures_lst = []
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
  for i in df.index:
    future = executor.submit(api_get_function, single_api_input_variable)
    futures_lst.append(future)

for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_lst):
  # First run a function to format the results returned by the API
  result_df = format_columns_in(future.result())
  # Append the formatted results to a csv file as we go
  result_df.to_csv('result.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You using `with` statement, that's why you will be blocked until all futures completed. `with` is special statement that is come with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. `__enter__` will be called when you enter the `with` block, and `__exit__` method will be called automatically(by interpreter) end of the with block.

When you look at the source code of `ThreadPoolExecutor` class, you will see this `__exit__` function (inherited from `Executor` class) :

```
def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    self.shutdown(wait=True)
    return False
```

And when we look at the description of [shutdown](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.shutdown) method, it says

> If wait is True then this method will not return until all the pending
> futures are done executing and the resources associated with the
> executor have been freed

That's why your code "is still waiting for all of the API queries to finish before it performs the subsequent actions".

To solve this, you have some option. First option is, you can remove the `with` statement. By doing this, you will not be blocked

```
futures_lst = []
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6)
for i in df.index:
    future = executor.submit(api_get_function, single_api_input_variable)
    futures_lst.append(future)

for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_lst):
  # First run a function to format the results returned by the API
  result_df = format_columns_in(future.result())
  # Append the formatted results to a csv file as we go
  result_df.to_csv('result.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)
```

But above option is not concurrent, because you looping over futures as they completed, but what if two of them are completed at the same time ?

If you want to do this operation concurrently(not parallel) you can use below option also:

```
def custom_callback(future):
    result_df = format_columns_in(future.result())
    # Append the formatted results to a csv file as we go
    result_df.to_csv('result.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
    for i in df.index:
        future = executor.submit(api_get_function, single_api_input_variable)
        future.add_done_callback(custom_callback)
```

This solution is concurrent, if any thread finish it's job, then it will call the `custom_callback` function

**But this option is not thread safe**, because you appending to file and I don't know what `format_columns_in` is do. `result_df.to_csv` require an extra locking(`format_columns_in` can also require locking accoring to its operation). You can do this option thread-safe like ;

Appending to file can be also thread safe, to more detail please look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12942915/understanding-concurrent-file-writes-from-multiple-processes)

```
def custom_callback(future):
    
    result_df = format_columns_in(future.result())
    # Append the formatted results to a csv file as we go
    with global_lock:
        result_df.to_csv('result.csv', mode='a', index=True, header=True)


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
    for i in df.index:
        future = executor.submit(api_get_function, single_api_input_variable)
        future.add_done_callback(custom_callback)
```

For more info about `add_done_callback()` method, you can see it from [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future.add_done_callback)