# Strange behavior of clone

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, clone, lightweight-processes

This is fairly simple application which creates a lightweight process (thread) with `clone()` call.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1024*1024

int func(void* param) {
    printf("I am func, pid %d\n", getpid());    
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("I am main, pid %d\n", getpid());
    void* ptr = malloc(STACK_SIZE);

    printf("I am calling clone\n");             
    int res = clone(func, ptr + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_VM, NULL);
    // works fine with sleep() call
    // sleep(1);

    if (res == -1) {
        printf("clone error: %d", errno);       
    } else {
        printf("I created child with pid: %d\n", res);      
    }

    printf("Main done, pid %d\n", getpid());        
    return 0;
}
```

Here are results:

**Run 1:**

```
➜  LFD401 ./clone
I am main, pid 10974
I am calling clone
I created child with pid: 10975
Main done, pid 10974
I am func, pid 10975
```

**Run 2:**

```
➜  LFD401 ./clone
I am main, pid 10995
I am calling clone
I created child with pid: 10996
I created child with pid: 10996
I am func, pid 10996
Main done, pid 10995
```

**Run 3:**

```
➜  LFD401 ./clone
I am main, pid 11037
I am calling clone
I created child with pid: 11038
I created child with pid: 11038
I am func, pid 11038
I created child with pid: 11038
I am func, pid 11038
Main done, pid 11037
```

**Run 4:**

```
➜  LFD401 ./clone
I am main, pid 11062
I am calling clone
I created child with pid: 11063
Main done, pid 11062
Main done, pid 11062
I am func, pid 11063
```

What is going on here? Why "I created child" message is sometimes printed several times?

Also I noticed that adding a delay after `clone` call "fixes" the problem.

Comment: Note that on a rare system where `int/unsigned` is 16-bit, yet `size_t` is 32-bit: `#define STACK_SIZE 1024*1024  void* ptr = malloc(STACK_SIZE);`  is a problem.  Anytime math is done in a "constant", watch out for overflow.  Suggest `#define STACK_SIZE ((size_t)1024*1024)`

Comment: Since it is apparently difficult to reproduce this problem, perhaps you would be so kind as to tell us some more about your architecture. Eg. OS and version; glibc version; gcc version. (Also any non-default compiler flags you use)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, GLIBC 2.23-0ubuntu3, gcc 5.4.0. CPU i7-5600U. No additional compiler flags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a race condition (i.e.) you don't have the implied thread safety of stdio.

The problem is even more severe. You can get duplicate "func" messages.

The problem is that using `clone` does not have the same guarantees as `pthread_create`. (i.e.) You do *not* get the thread safe variants of `printf`.

I don't know for sure, but, IMO the verbiage about stdio streams and thread safety, in practice, only applies when using `pthreads`.

So, you'll have to handle your own interthread locking.

Here is a version of your program recoded to use `pthread_create`. It seems to work without incident:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1024*1024

void *func(void* param) {
    printf("I am func, pid %d\n", getpid());
    return (void *) 0;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("I am main, pid %d\n", getpid());
    void* ptr = malloc(STACK_SIZE);

    printf("I am calling clone\n");

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid,NULL,func,NULL);
    //int res = clone(func, ptr + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_VM, NULL);
    int res = 0;

    // works fine with sleep() call
    // sleep(1);

    if (res == -1) {
        printf("clone error: %d", errno);
    } else {
        printf("I created child with pid: %d\n", res);
    }

    pthread_join(tid,NULL);
    printf("Main done, pid %d\n", getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a test script I've been using to check for errors [it's a little rough, but should be okay]. Run against your version and it will abort quickly. The `pthread_create` version seems to pass just fine

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# clonetest -- clone test
#
# arguments:
#   "-p0" -- suppress check for duplicate parent messages
#   "-c0" -- suppress check for duplicate child messages
#   1 -- base name for program to test (e.g. for xyz.c, use xyz)
#   2 -- [optional] number of test iterations (DEFAULT: 100000)

master(@ARGV);
exit(0);

# master -- master control
sub master
{
    my(@argv) = @_;
    my($arg,$sym);

    while (1) {
        $arg = $argv[0];
        last unless (defined($arg));

        last unless ($arg =~ s/^-(.)//);
        $sym = $1;

        shift(@argv);

        $arg = 1
            if ($arg eq "");

        $arg += 0;
        ${"opt_$sym"} = $arg;
    }

    $opt_p //= 1;
    $opt_c //= 1;
    printf("clonetest: p=%d c=%d\n",$opt_p,$opt_c);

    $xfile = shift(@argv);
    $xfile //= "clone1";
    printf("clonetest: xfile='%s'\n",$xfile);

    $itermax = shift(@argv);
    $itermax //= 100000;
    $itermax += 0;
    printf("clonetest: itermax=%d\n",$itermax);

    system("cc -o $xfile -O2 $xfile.c -lpthread");
    $code = $? >> 8;
    die("master: compile error\n")
        if ($code);

    $logf = "/tmp/log";

    for ($iter = 1;  $iter <= $itermax;  ++$iter) {
        printf("iter: %d\n",$iter)
            if ($opt_v);
        dotest($iter);
    }
}

# dotest -- perform single test
sub dotest
{
    my($iter) = @_;
    my($parcnt,$cldcnt);
    my($xfsrc,$bf);

    system("./$xfile > $logf");

    open($xfsrc,"<$logf") or
        die("dotest: unable to open '$logf' -- $!\n");

    while ($bf = <$xfsrc>) {
        chomp($bf);

        if ($opt_p) {
            while ($bf =~ /created/g) {
                ++$parcnt;
            }
        }

        if ($opt_c) {
            while ($bf =~ /func/g) {
                ++$cldcnt;
            }
        }
    }

    close($xfsrc);

    if (($parcnt > 1) or ($cldcnt > 1)) {
        printf("dotest: fail on %d -- parcnt=%d cldcnt=%d\n",
            $iter,$parcnt,$cldcnt);
        system("cat $logf");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Were you able to recreate OPs problem with clone?

Absolutely. Before I created the pthreads version, in addition to testing OP's original version, I also created versions that:

(1) added `setlinebuf` to the start of `main`

(2) added `fflush` just before the `clone` and `__fpurge` as the first statement of `func`

(3) added an `fflush` in `func` before the `return 0`

Version (2) eliminated the duplicate parent messages, but the duplicate child messages remained

If you'd like to see this for yourself, download OP's version from the question, my version, and the test script. Then, run the test script on OP's version.

I posted enough information and files so that anyone can recreate the problem.

Note that due to differences between my system and OP's, I couldn't at first reproduce the problem on just 3-4 tries. So, that's why I created the script.

The script does 100,000 test runs and usually the problem will manifest itself within 5000-15000.

Comment: Were you able to recreate OPs problem with clone?

Comment: @evaitl Yes, absolutely. See my updated answer for more details.

Comment: Very cool +1. I wasn't planning on using clone(), but now I have a reason.

Answer (score 3):

I can't recreate OP's issue, but I don't think the printf's are actually a problem.

[glibc docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Threads.html):

> The POSIX standard requires that by default the stream operations are
>   atomic. I.e., issuing two stream operations for the same stream in two
>   threads at the same time will cause the operations to be executed as
>   if they were issued sequentially. The buffer operations performed
>   while reading or writing are protected from other uses of the same
>   stream. To do this each stream has an internal lock object which has
>   to be (implicitly) acquired before any work can be done.

**Edit:**

Even though the above is true for threads, as rici points out, there is a comment on [sourceware](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10311#c6):

> Basically, there's nothing you can safely do with CLONE_VM unless the
>   child restricts itself to pure computation and direct syscalls (via
>   sys/syscall.h). If you use any of the standard library, you risk the
>   parent and child clobbering each other's internal states. You also
>   have issues like the fact that glibc caches the pid/tid in userspace,
>   and the fact that glibc expects to always have a valid thread pointer
>   which your call to clone is unable to initialize correctly because it
>   does not know (and should not know) the internal implementation of
>   threads.

Apparently, glibc isn't designed to work with clone if CLONE_VM is set but CLONE_THREAD|CLONE_SIGHAND are not.

Answer (score 2):

Your processes both use the same `stdout` (that is, the C standard library `FILE` struct), which includes an accidentally shared buffer. That's undoubtedly causing problems.

Comment: glibc printf is supposed to be [thread safe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/468105/5058676)

Comment: @evaitl However, `clone()` doesn't "officially" create a thread. So there may be some additional setup required that isn't happening.

Comment: I suppose, but I don't see the difference. The glibc docs [confirm](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Streams-and-Threads.html) that there is no problem with multiple threads writing to output: *"yes, the same job could be done with one fprintf call but it is sometimes not possible"*. Incidentally, I can't recreate OPs problem.

Comment: @evaitl: Yeah, I can't reproduce it either (now that I have a computer in front of me to try it with.) It's possible that this comment by Rich Felker is relevant: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=10311#c6

Comment: @rici I wish he had linked to some kind of authoritative source. Also I wish the problem were reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

Ass everyone suggests: it really seems to be a problem with, how shall I put it in case of `clone()`, process-safety? With a rough sketch of a locking version of printf (using `write(2)`) the output is as expected.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1024*1024

// VERY rough attempt at a thread-safe printf
#include <stdarg.h>
#define SYNC_REALLOC_GROW 64
int sync_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
  int n, all = 0;
  int size = 256;
  char *p, *np;
  va_list args;

  if ((p = malloc(size)) == NULL)
    return -1;

  for (;;) {
    va_start(args, format);
    n = vsnprintf(p, size, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    if (n < 0)
      return -1;
    all += n;
    if (n < size)
      break;
    size = n + SYNC_REALLOC_GROW;
    if ((np = realloc(p, size)) == NULL) {
      free(p);
      return -1;
    } else {
      p = np;
    }
  }
  // write(2) shoudl be threadsafe, so just in case
  flockfile(stdout);
  n = (int) write(fileno(stdout), p, all);
  fflush(stdout);
  funlockfile(stdout);
  va_end(args);
  free(p);
  return n;
}


int func(void *param)
{
  sync_printf("I am func, pid %d\n", getpid());
  return 0;
}

int main()
{

  sync_printf("I am main, pid %d\n", getpid());
  void *ptr = malloc(STACK_SIZE);

  sync_printf("I am calling clone\n");
  int res = clone(func, ptr + STACK_SIZE, CLONE_VM, NULL);
  // works fine with sleep() call
  // sleep(1);

  if (res == -1) {
    sync_printf("clone error: %d", errno);
  } else {
    sync_printf("I created child with pid: %d\n", res);
  }
  sync_printf("Main done, pid %d\n\n", getpid());
  return 0;
}
```

For the third time: it's only a sketch, no time for a robust version, but that shouldn't hinder you to write one.

Answer (score 2):

As [evaitl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5058676/evaitl) points out `printf` is documented to be thread-safe by glibc's documentation. **BUT**, this typically assumes that you are using the designated glibc function to create threads (that is, `pthread_create()`). If you do not, then you are on your own.

The lock  taken by `printf()` is [recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrant_mutex) (see `flockfile`). This means that if the lock is already taken, the implementation checks the owner of the lock against the locker. If the locker is the same as the owner, the locking attempt succeeds.

To distinguish between different threads, you need to setup properly [TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage), which you do not do, but `pthread_create()` does. What I'm guessing happens is that in your case the TLS variable that identifies the thread is the same for both threads, so you end up taking the lock.

TL;DR: please use `pthread_create()`