# Segmentation Fault - Producer Consumer

Tags: c, producer-consumer, producer

This is my basic code , now the problem is that it runs for couple of loops and then gives segmentation fault. Now I know that segmentation error is due to illegal read/write at a memory location, but I haven't used any pointers on that note.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int counter = 0;
int BUFFER_SIZE = 5;
int buffer[] = {0};
int in = 0;
int out = 0;
void *prod(char);
void *cons(void);
bool flag = true;

void main()
{   int i, j;

    pthread_t thread1, thread2; 
    do{

            flag = true;
            i = pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, prod('i'), NULL);
            flag = true;
            j = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, cons(), NULL);

    }while(1);
}

void* prod(char a)
{
    while (flag) {
      printf("\nCounter  = %d", counter);

while (counter == BUFFER_SIZE) {
      printf("\nBusy Waiting!!!");
} 

buffer[in] = a;
in = (in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
printf("\nProducer produced an item %c!",a);
counter++;
printf("\nTotal items produced = %d",counter);

flag = false;

}
}

void* cons()
{
  char a;
  while (flag) {
    printf("\nCounter  = %d",counter);
    while (counter == 0){printf("\nBusy Waiting!!!");
  } 

  a = buffer[out];
  out = (out + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;

  counter--;

  printf("\nTotal items remaining = %d",counter);
  flag = false;
}
}
```

[OUPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4Xx8.png)

Comment: You are creating infinitely many threads. Two every iteration to be exact.

Comment: But the error I am getting is after 1 or 2 times the function is called @StoryTeller

Comment: No, you get it after you saw input about two times. Thread creation can happens much faster than that. That's a big mistake with your program.

Comment: Why do `prod` and `cons` lack a return statement?

Comment: And you need to provide a function pointer to a thread procedure, while your code calls these functions (`cons()`) and uses their results as pointers to thread functions. Neither cons nor prod return anything which makes a return value undefined. When pthread_create starts a thread with such pointer to function, it simply crashes.

Comment: Ok so will I have to create the thread only once and then run it ? @StoryTeller

Comment: A producer consumer model involves a finite number of threads, that use **proper synchronization** to access an abstract queue in a loop. The in-a-loop part means the threads execute a loop, not that they are created in a loop without stop.

Comment: @MaksimSkurydzin you should post this as an answer.

Comment: @MaksimSkurydzin Then how are they running once or twice and then giving error ? Shouldn't they give error then and there ?

Comment: @MaksimSkurydzin pthread accepts functions with return type (void*)

Comment: Overall, you need to actually study how threads work before using them... This program has so many problems.

Comment: @GunjanRaval `pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, prod, NULL);` After the threads are created, you can wait on their completion using `pthread_join` on each of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple severe bugs:

- You are creating threads in an eternal loop, until the program runs out of memory. What you want to do is to just create *n* threads once, then let the main program loop (forever?) after that.
- `pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, prod('i'), NULL)` is incorrect, you are *calling* the callback function here instead of providing a function pointer to it. Arguments to the callback need to be passed separately. Read the manual about `pthread_create`.
- pthreads expect a function format of the type `void* func (void*)`. You are not allowed to use any other function format. So both of your callback functions have the wrong format.
- You aren't using any form of protection mechanism for variables shared between multiple threads. You need to use a mutex or similar.
- stdio.h is not necessarily thread-safe, depending on which system and C standard version you are using. See [stdout thread-safe in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/467938/stdout-thread-safe-in-c-on-linux).

Comment: Thanks Man ! Got it I wasn't using the function format correctly !.

Comment: @GunjanRaval Please note that you need to fix _all_ of the above concerns. These aren't some minor nit-picks but all of them are severe bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the loop one time and use `pthread_join` to wait for created thread(s). The while loop creates new threads and re-write the handles (`thread1` and `thread2`) which is most probably what is causing crash.

Comment: But I want these threads to run infinitely, then what can I do ?

Comment: Overwritting the `pthread_t` variables is no problem, it is only some kind of integer to identify the thread. The real problem are the function calls in `pthread_create(..)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your segfault is mostly sure due to the `buffer` array. You are defining an array of size 1 and later in the code you are using up to 5 positions.

You are defining it as:

```
int BUFFER_SIZE = 5;
int buffer[] = {0};
```

That actually creates a buffer that can only hold 1 int (because you are using an initializer with just one value).

Then you are indexing it modulo `BUFFER_SIZE`:

```
buffer[in] = a;
in = (in + 1) % BUFFER_SIZE;
```

And that will overflow `buffer` after the first iteration (when `in` is greater than 0, and you are trying to index a position that is not allocated -or, better said, part of the memory allocated for `buffer`).

You think that you aren't using pointers, but under the hoods, you are. In C, the array indexing `buffer[in]` is equivalent to `*(buffer + in)`, so you are in fact "using pointers" in your code.